# Safari error on login Microsoft account with oauth2

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, nativescript, mobile-safari, nativescript-oauth2

I have a a problem on a **Nativescript 5.1.0** project with **Angular 4**, I use the API **nativescript-oauth2**, and it works fine for *Facebook* and *Google*, but when I try to Login into **Microsoft** it does not do very well.

I can enter the e-mail account and password, even the permission screen is shown, but in this one when I press YES it crashes.

[image: before crashes]

[image: Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid]

The problem is because of the property **redirect uri** (*urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob*) for the Microsoft configuration,  when Safari receives the redirect uri, Safari crashes.

I read that can be solved with a delegate, but it already exists in the **nativescript-oauth2**.

And the android browser does not show the error but it does nothing.

Help me please!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Microsoft oAuth, it tries to open your app with an URL scheme. You might want to setup URL schemes in your app like it's showcased in demo app for [Provider](https://github.com/alexziskind1/nativescript-oauth2/blob/master/demo-angular/src/app/auth-providers-helper.ts#L56), [iOS](https://github.com/alexziskind1/nativescript-oauth2/blob/master/demo/app/App_Resources/iOS/Info.plist#L56) & [Android](https://github.com/alexziskind1/nativescript-oauth2/blob/master/demo/app/App_Resources/Android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L29)

Comment: Thanks a lot , It works very well. I already was trying with my own scheme but the problem was that I did not specify it in the **info.plist** and the **manifest**.
Thanks, again.